# Non constant Feature Importance

Tags: features, statistics, feature-engineering, random-forests

I have a financial dataset which has 10 years worth of data. The aim is to build a regressor capable of predicting next year sales. So, if I want to predict sales for 2024, I could use data from 2023, 2022, 2021, and so on...

If I use all my features, I'm able to get a decent model, but with some feature selection/engineering, I believe we can have much better model, because some of my features are very noisy. So, I was trying to apply MDA (Mean Decrease accuracy) and analyze feature importance for a Random Forest, but the big thing is, the feature importance keeps varying a lot from year to year, so its really hard to select which features are noise and which are not.

For instance, for 2023 the inflation is a very important feature, but back in 2018 it was not that important and was only adding noise. I thought about adding more features or trying to differentiate my features in order to have something more stable, but no success yet.

So my question is, **what are the best ways to tackle this?**

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can derive new features that should be more stable over time using PCA. A more simple approaches is to calculate the technical indicators of these numerical features such as RSI, moving average as they will represent the trend more effectively.